# 画面遷移先が意図したようにならない

Tags: swift

「ほんきで学ぶSwift＋iosアプリ開発入門」というSwift2の本を参考にSwift4で作成した下記のコードで画面遷移先が意図したようになりません。
このコードでは初期画面のtableViewに新規作成用の＋ボタンと作成保存した日記の一覧が表示されています。どちらかを選びSegueで画面遷移する際にprepareForSegueメソッドが呼ばれますが、Segueに名前をaddSegue、cellSegueとつけることで、新規作成と作成保存した画面とに中の処理を分けて表示させようとしています。
作成保存した日記の一覧から選んだときにcellSegueで記録された日記がでることを意図しているのですが、新規作成の画面が出てしまいます。作成保存した画面が出てこないのです。

＜疑問点＞
①Main.storyboardで初期画面であるViewControllerから遷移先のinputViewControllerに右クリックしながらドラック＆ドロップしてsegueを作成し、IdentifierをcellSegueにすると本にありました。この時に、本のとおりにできないところがありました。それはtableViewの大きな四角い画面からはinputViewControllerへ右クリックしながらドラック＆ドロップしても無反応でManualSegueを作成できなかったのです。それで、tableViewの大きな四角い画面の上部にあるViewControllerのアイコンをクリックしてドラック＆ドロップしてsegueを作成し、IdentifierをcellSegueにしました。
これが原因なのかなと思っています。しかし、そうするとこの場合はどのようにすれば良いのでしょうか。

②コードの中にswift４にした場合の問題があるのではないかとも思っています。この場合はどこが問題なのでしょうか。

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    //デフォルトのレルムのインスタンスを作る
    let realm = try! Realm()
    //DB内のデータが格納されるリスト、日付順でソート・アップデートするとリスト内を自動更新
    let dataArray = try! Realm().objects(Diary.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "date", ascending: false)
    //`DateFormatter`のインスタンスを作ってプロパティに保持しておく
    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        //デバイスの各種設定(タイムゾーン含む)に合わせ、システム標準の書式.mediumを使用する
        df.dateStyle = .medium
        df.timeStyle = .medium
        return df
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    //入力画面から戻ってきたときにテーブルビューを更新させる
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    //segueで画面遷移するときに呼ばれる
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        let inputViewController: inputViewController = segue.destination as! inputViewController
        if segue.identifier == "cellSegue"{
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            inputViewController.diary = dataArray[indexPath!.row]

        } else {
            let diary = Diary()
            diary.title = "タイトル"
            diary.body = "本文"
            if dataArray.count != 0 {
                diary.id = dataArray.max(ofProperty: "id")! + 1
            }
            inputViewController.diary = diary
        }
    }

    //各sectionのセルの数を返す
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
    }
//セルの内容
    func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
//再利用可能なセル
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
//セルに値を設定する
        let object = dataArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = object.title

        //cell.detailTextLabel?.text = object.date.description の行を以下のように変更
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateFormatter.string(from: object.date as Date)
        return cell
    }
//セルが削除可能なことを
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete;
    }

  //各セルを選択したときに実行
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "cellSegue", sender: nil)
    }


//deleteボタンが押されたときの処理
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete{
            try! realm.write{
                self.realm.delete(self.dataArray[indexPath.row])

            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
       }
   }
}
```

}

Comment: 前質問で Tatsuhiro SAWA さんからいただいたコメントの後半部分はきちんとチェックされましたでしょうか? ご質問本文中では、一貫して **cellSegue** と表記されているのに対して、コード中では`"cellsegue"`となっている部分がありますが?

Comment: 了解しました。cellSegueがこのSegueにつけた識別子なのでこれに直しました。しかし結果は同じで、作成保存した画面には‌​遷移しませんでした。

Comment: ご質問の修正と動作のご確認ありがとうございました。そのような症状になるのであれば、クラス`inputViewController`側に問題がある可能性が高いと思われます。(直接この件の原因になっている可能性は低いと思いますが、「Swiftでは型名は大文字で始める」と言うルールがよく守られています。Q&Aサイトの利用を含めて、コードを多人数に見てもらう可能性がある場合には、そういったルールは守られた方が良いでしょう。またSwiftの構文規則ではプロパティやローカル変数名と同名の型が存在すると、構文解析に失敗する可能性が他の言語よりも高くなっています。可能な限り同じ名前にするのは避けた方が良いでしょう。)念のため、`prepare(for:sender:)`内の`segue.identifier == "cellSegue"`側のコードが実行されていることは確かめられたでしょうか?`inputViewController.diary = dataArray[indexPath!.row]`の上にブレークポイントを置く等すれば、簡単に確かめられるはずです。

Comment: 了解しました。inputViewController.d‌​iary = dataArray[indexPath!.row]の上にブレークポイントを設定して実行すると入力して保存まで進行し、保存‌​したものを開けようとすると、ちゃんとブレ‌​ークポイントで止まります。その上の override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){のところにブレークポイントを設定して＋ボタンと、作成保存したものを開くをそれぞれ実行して一旦止まってからst‌​ep overで動作させて見ると、この次のif文では意図どおり分岐します。(＋ボタン→else{ let diary = Diary()以下へ。作成保存したものを開く→let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow以下の実行)

Comment: ご報告されたようにif文が意図通りに分岐していると言うのであれば、問題は`inputViewController`クラスの方にあると言うことになりますね。同クラスの動作をよく確認された上で、ご自身で解決できないようであれば、ご質問にクラスの定義一式を追加してください。(ご自身で解決できた場合は、解決内容が他の読者にもわかるように、ご回答をご自身で投稿してください。)

Comment: 了解しました。inputViewControllerクラスのoverride func viewDidLoad() に titleTextField.text = diary.titleと bodyTextView.text = diary.bodyが抜けていました。問題は解決しました。感謝します。

Answer (score 0):

inputViewControllerクラスのoverride func viewDidLoad() に 次のコードが抜けていました。

```
titleTextField.text = diary.title
bodyTextView.text = diary.body
```